# Can I ask questions that address ORIGINAL critical thinking or only seek guidance in a pool of research?

Tags: discussion

Posting question on skeptics.se requires citing sources. What if the nature of the question is addressing *original* critical thinking, and not just navigating through available research? After all, skepticism is sometimes the main "weapon" *against* available research (if any).